Nail length for 2x10 joist hangers and hurricane ties on 2x10 header and 2x10 (x3) beam
I need to attach 2x10 joists to a 2x10 header/ledger and beam (3x 2x10) and I'm having trouble finding information on the required nail size for a sturdy connections. Currently, I have...

Simpson Strong Tie LUS210Z Joist Hangers
Simpson Smooth Shank Connector Nails, 10d x 1½"

Yet to purchase... additional nails and ties to connect the joist and the beam.
The questions...

Do I need to purchase different nails for the joist hanger to header connection?
Worth noting, due the structure of my house and the location of the deck portions of the header do not connect to the house's rim joist but rather the framing via 5" Simpsons Strong-Drive SDWS Timber screws. I originally thought the 1½" would be preferred for the hangers so that I do not penetrate beyond the header into empty space. But is 2½" or larger required? Is there any additional strength if a nail extends beyond the wood?

What size hurricane ties and nails should I use for the joist to beam connection?


The joists are 12' in length.

The Simpson catalog (available on-line) has all the info you need.  In addition to the load carrying capacity for the "standard" nailing schedule, it also has load capacities for when you use shorter nails, Simpson strong tie lag screws, etc.

Yes it will take different sizes.
The required nail sizes are stamped in the metal of the hangers. The angle they go in, and their length as well. This is for Simpson, other makers may not have this.
It is usually 3", maybe 3 1/2" nails on the angle, 1 1/4" to 1 1/2" straight into the sides of the joists.

The nail sizes were not stamped on the Simpson hangers in my case, but they were listed on the box at the hardware store. 10d 3" nails for the angle was the ticket. Thanks!
